# keep error register symfony

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm looking to do some correction to my register form.

The problem is that in my login.html.twig, I can do anything how:

```
{% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}
```

In my register_content.html.twig, I cannot do that, the errors, for example, not 2 same usernames, is writen directly at the top of my username label.

How can I modify this one? For example to be in red?

I imagine, that this is created directly be my validator, but how can I catch them?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this: In your twig file render field like

```
<label>{{ form_label(form.username) }}</label>
{{ form_widget(form.username) }}
<span class="error">
     {{form_errors(form.username)}}
</span>
```

Prepare your css like:

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

You can add any style as per your requirement. As i know this error will come in 'ul' tag. You can also use that in your css.